# CPLEX Studio solve MIP problem forever, what should I do?

Tags: cplex, docplex, docplexcloud

everyone I have tried to solve a MIP problem with CPLEX Studio. Now it's 8 hrs. still not find the solution. I am minimizing distance of waste collection. Details are as follows:
The data is matrix of 49 rows * 49 columns.
Decision Variable: 3
Internal Data: 6
External Data:8
Constraints: 11

I have tried the same code with small problem (matrix 7*7), and it worked absolutely fine.

I would like to know what I should do to make it faster. please help